# PHP constructor parameter not working properly?

Tags: php

Somehow my constructor doesn`t seem to work properly:

```
private $matchId;
private $region;
private $date;
private $wAdc;
private $wSupp;
private $lAdc;
private $lSupp;
private $summoners;

public function _construct($matchId, $region, $date) {
    $this->matchId = $matchId;
    $this->region = $region;
    $this->date = $date;
    $this->summoners = array();
    $this->wAdc = null;
    $this->wSupp = null;
    $this->lAdc = null;
    $this->lSupp = null;
}

public function getMatchId() {
    return $this->matchId;
}
```

And here the object creation:

```
$matchObj = new match($matchId, $region, $created);
$matches[] = $matchObj;
echo "a: ". $matchId . " ";
echo "b: ". $matchObj->getMatchId() . " ";
```

And here the output I get when I run the script in my browser:

```
a: 1936074952 b:
```

So the object variable doesn`t seem to get set properly. Could anybody help me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot a underscore

It should be `public function __construct()`

Comment: You mean an underscore ;)

Comment: @Machavity True I forgot the english translation.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem!

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your constructor, try this:

```
public function __construct($matchId, $region, $date) {...}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem!